# Weird spaces in HTML

Tags: php, html

I have three php files :

- MusicStore/templates/header.php
- MusicStore/templates/navbar.php
- MusicStore/accueil.php

in header.php I have :

```
<?php
function    get_header()
{
    echo "<header class=\"header\">";
    echo "<div class=\"banniere\">";
    echo "<a href=\"accueil.php\"><img src=\"http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/logo.png\" alt=\"banniere\"/></a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</header>";
}
?>
```

in accueil.php :

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    require_once('./templates/navbar.php');
    require_once('./templates/header.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="html">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Music Store</title>
    </head>

    <body class="body_accueil"><?php
        get_header();
        get_navbar();
        ?>

        <section>
            <article>
                <div class="new">
                    <a class="new_new" href="nouveaute.html">NOUVEAUTE</a>
                    <div class="podhd500x">
                        <a href="produits/159862.html"><img class="img_product" src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/pedaliers/podhd500x.jpg" alt="LINE 6 POD HD500X"/></a>
                        <div class="description">
                            <a class="product_name" href="produits/159862.html">LINE 6 - POD HD500X</a>
                            <p>Découvrez le nouveau POD HD500X!</p>
                            <a href="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/templates/line6.html"><img src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/marques/line6.jpg" alt="LINE 6"/></a>
                            <p><span class="prix">498.00€</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="molotov">
                        <a href="produits/136803.html"><img class="img_product" src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/pedales/eagletone%20molotov.jpg" alt="EAGLETONE MOLOTOV"/></a>
                        <div class="description">
                            <a class="product_name" href="produits/136803.html">EAGLETONE - MOLOTOV</a>
                            <p>Nouvelle pédale à distortion de chez EAGLETONE! Procurez-vous un son extra saturé!</p>
                            <a href="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/templates/eagletone.html"><img src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/marques/eagletone.jpg" alt="EAGLETONE"/></a>
                            <p><span class="prix">39.00€</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="microcube">
                        <a href="produits/164183.html"><img class="img_product" src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/amplificateurs/rolandmicrocubegxw.jpg" alt="ROLAND MICRO CUBE GXW BLANC"/></a>
                        <div class="description">
                            <a class="product_name" href="produits/164183.html">ROLAND - MICRO CUBE GXW BLANC</a>
                            <p>Découvrez chez ROLAND les nouveaux modèles micro cube. Rapport qualité prix garantie!</p>
                            <a href="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/templates/roland.html"><img src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/marques/roland.jpg" alt="ROLAND"/></a>
                            <p><span class="prix">129.00€</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="evhwhite">
                        <a href="produits/151709.html"><img class="img_product" src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/guitares/evh/evhwhite.jpg" alt="EVH STRIPE SERIES BLANC NOIR"/></a>
                        <div class="description">
                            <a class="product_name" href="produits/151709.html">EVH - STRIPE SERIES BLANC/NOIR</a>
                            <p>La nouvelle gamme EVH, offre de superbe guitares pour pas cher!</p>
                            <a href="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/templates/roland.html"><img src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/marques/evh.jpg" alt="EVH"/></a>
                            <p><span class="prix">588.00€</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- END DIV NEW ARTICLE -->
            </article> <!-- END ARTICLE -->

            <article>
                <div class="top">
                    <a class="top_top" href="pages/topvente.html">MEILLEURS VENTES</a>
                    <div class="vente">
                        <a href="produits/68102.html"><img class="img_guitare" src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/guitares/ltd/ltdalexi600.jpg" alt="LTD ALEXI600 BLACKY SIGNATURE"/></a>
                        <a href="produits/121546.html"><img class="img_p" src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/amplificateurs/orangedarkterror.jpg" alt="ORANGE DARK TERROR"/></a>
                        <a href="produits/126222.html"><img class="img_guitare" src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/guitares/ibanez/s5470q.jpg" alt="IBANEZ PRESTIGE S5470Q"/></a>
                        <a href="produits/19491.html"><img class="img_p" src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/accessoires/fastfret.jpg" alt="FAST FRET"/></a>
                        <a href="produits/125415.html"><img class="img_p" src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/accessoires/eagletonemediato.jpg" alt="EAGLETONE MEDIATOR SET"/></a>
                        <a href="produits/163240.html"><img class="img_p" src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/jeux/rocksmith2014ps3.jpg" alt="ROCKSMITH 2014 PS3"/></a>
                        <a href="produits/86268.html"><img class="img_p" src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/partitions/megadeth%20countdown%20to%20extinction.jpg" alt="MEGADETH : COUNTDOWN TO EXTINCTION"/></a>
                        <a href="produits/66588.html"><img class="img_p" src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/partitions/little%20black%20book%20of%20metal%20hits.jpg" alt="LITTLE BLACK BOOK OF METAL HITS"/></a>
                        <a href="produits/164183.html"><img class="img_p" src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/amplificateurs/rolandmicrocubegxw.jpg" alt="ROLAND MICRO CUBE"/></a>
                        <a href="produits/159501.html"><img class="img_torpedo" src="http://localhost/e-commerce/MusicStore/img/pedales/torpedocab.jpg" alt="TORPEDO CAB"/></a>
                        <a href="nouveaute.html" class="suivant">Suivant >></a>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- END TOP ARTICLE -->
            </article> 
        </section> <!-- END SECTION -->

        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="bloc1">
                <h3><a href="contact.html">Envie de nous contacter?</a></h3>
                <p>Conseil et commande au téléphone :<br />du lundi au vendredi de 9h à 20h, le samedi de 10h à 19h.</p>
                <p>France métropolitaine<br /><strong class="numero">01 48 05 86 12</strong><br />Appel gratuit depuis un poste fixe.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="bloc2">
                <h3>Horaires</h3>
                <p>Ouvert du lundi au samedi de 9h à 21h non-stop.</p><p><em>1 Avenue Malanco<br />75001 Paris.<br />Station Malanco, métro ligne 12.</em></p>
            </div>

            <div class="bloc3">
                <h3>Informations utiles!</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="nouveaute.html" title="Nouveauté">Nouveauté</a></li>
                    <li><a href="nous.html" title="Qui sommes nous?">Qui sommes nous?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="condition.html" title="Conditions générales de vente">Conditions générales de vente</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </footer> <!-- END FOOTER -->
    </body> <!-- END BODY -->
</html>
```

When I go to the accueil.php, I have my header with the website's logo, and the navbar but when I inspect the element, I have this stuff :

```
[Screenshot] removed because it contains offensive language
```

It looks like to be generated by my get_header(); before the echo.. and when I delete on my broswer the string, my logo is in top of the page like I had without functions. So the strings make a margin-bottom ..

Do you have some ideas of this mistake?

UPDATE navbar.php :

```
<?php
function    get_navbar()
{
    echo "<nav class=\"menu\">
            <div class=\"block_menu\">
                <ul class=\"niveau1\">
                    <li class=\"border2\"><a href=\"accueil.html\"><strong class=\"accueil\">Accueil</strong></a></li>
                    <li class=\"border\"><a href=\"nouveaute.html\"><strong class=\"nouveaute\">Nouveauté</strong></a></li>
                    <li class=\"border\">Guitares
                        <ul class=\"niveau2\">
                            <li class=\"border3\"><a href=\"accessoires.html\">Accessoires guitares</a>
                                <ul class=\"niveau3\">
                                    <li><a href=\"accordeurs.html\">Accordeurs</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"cables.html\">Cables</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"cordes.html\">Cordes</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"mediators.html\">Médiators</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"micros.html\">Micros guitare</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"pieces.html\">Pièces détachées</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"piles.html\">Piles</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"entretiens.html\">Produits d'entretien</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"sangles.html\">Sangles guitare</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"stands.html\">Stands guitare</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class=\"border3\"><a href=\"amplis_et_effets.html\">Amplis et effets</a>
                                <ul class=\"niveau4\">
                                    <li><a href=\"ampli.html\">Ampli</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"effets.hmtl\">Effets</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class=\"border3\"><a href=\"guitares.html\">Guitares électriques</a>
                                <ul class=\"niveau5\">
                                    <li><a href=\"customshop.html\">Custom Shop ESP</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"8cordes.html\">8 Cordes</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"7cordes.html\">7 Cordes</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=\"metal.html\">Métal</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class=\"border3\"><a href=\"jeux.html\">Jeux video</a>
                        <ul class=\"niveau6\">
                            <li><a href=\"rocksmith12.html\">Rocksmith</a></li>
                            <li><a href=\"rocksmith14.html\">Rocksmith 2014</a></li>
                            <li><a href=\"bandfuse.html\">BandFuse: Rock Legends</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class=\"border3\"><a href=\"partitions.html\">Partitions</a>
                        <ul class=\"niveau7\">
                            <li><a href=\"tab_metal.html\">Partitions Metal</a></li>
                            <li><a href=\"tab_rock.html\">Partitions Rock</a></li>
                            <li><a href=\"tab_classique.html\">Partitions Classique</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class=\"border\"><a href=\"marques.html\">Nos Marques</a></li>
                    <li class=\"border\"><a href=\"panier.html\">Panier</a></li>
                    <li class=\"border\"><a href=\"contact.html\">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>";
}
?>
```

So, I added all my 'require' before `<!DOCTYPE html>` and I still have the weird spaces same if I have `<?php after <body>`..

NEW SCREENSHOT : [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tjND.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the body tag adjacent to the PHP open tag. So change:

```
<body class="body_accueil">     
<?php
```

into

```
<body class="body_accueil"><?php
```

And that stuff will probably be gone. But you can simply ignore that stuff. It will cause no harm.

Comment: In addition, when in doubt, make sure to choose 'View source' in your browser. That will show the exact source as it is. When you inspect the DOM, you might be fooled by the way the browser presents this information. In this case it quotes whitespace for clarity. In other cases, it might change or add missing closing tags or do other kinds of reformatting. Very convenient, but when in doubt, just use the source, Luke.

Comment: Other addition: That stuff (whitespace) will *usually* not cause any harm. A series of spaces and line breaks collapse to a single space. Normally this isn't a problem at all, but in some cases those spaces can be in the way. For instance when you have 2 elements, you make them `display: block` and `width: 50%`, they should fit next to each other. But when there is whitespace inbetween it won't work, and they will occupy two lines. In that case, you'll have to use @nl-x's solution.

Comment: Yep thanks, it works fine, I don't understand how it can works.. =)

Comment: @SamiJnih It is because the browser engine is parsing your HTML tag-soup and rendering it to a DOM document. Your browser formally sees the white space as important data that should not just be discarded. So it takes that white space and gives it its place in the DOM document.

Answer (score 0):

You directly `include` ("`require_once`) the php-file navbar within your html `body`.
So it seems that maybe you have some **blank lines** in your `navbar.php` **before** your **`<?php`** statement. Please check for this and if delete them. Also i would recommend to write all includes and requires on top of a file within an own `<?php ... ?>`-Block.

If that doesn't help you please provide all your files to analyse your problem.

Comment: I tried to put all my require before <!DOCTYPE html> but in the inspector, I have 

"<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css" />
  <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Music Store</title> "
 into the <body>.. and not into the <head></head> :o

Comment: Never mind what the Inspector shows, see what will be produced in the HTML source instead; that's what counts. @SamiJnih

Comment: You're welcome @SamiJnih when in doubt of errors, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) (inside PHP) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` that will show you if you have any real errors or not.

Comment: If the inspector tool is right, than its probably possible that your html tags don't match each other. Please check this and maybe strip your application down to a sceleton to isolate your error.

Comment: Thanks, I'll now use this.